# How to force Aurelia to destroy/recreate a view/viewModel pair without using router

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-templating

It came as a surprise when starting out with Aurelia that `if.bind` doesn't result in a child view/viewModel getting destroyed.  It does go through a bind/unbind attached/detached cycle, and I can see how this makes sense for some scenarios.  But I would also like the ability to completely destroy the view/viewModel and recreate it from scratch.  I've created a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ReZ6UL91MCDffg0tLiGE?p=preview) that demonstrates my best effort using `if.bind`.  I'm looking for suggestions on how to have the <my-other-element> completely destroyed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can use the `<compose>` element to treat the custom element as a view/view model and therefore use transient creation behavior.  [See `compose` documentation](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/templating/latest/templating-basics/4)

plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/vKsQsHKsIp4vTVjG5G7f?p=preview

```
<template if.bind="someBoolean">
  <compose view-model="my-other-element.js"></compose>
</template>
```

Comment: This is nicer than my first hack of using `repeat.for`.  I would still consider this a hack since I believe compose is intended for situations where one might use different kinds of viewModels.  Also Jeremy Danyow [recommends](https://www.danyow.net/aurelia-custom-element-vs-compose/) using Custom Elements over Compose whereever possible.  Also of note is that `@transient` doesn't make a difference in this situation, the view/viewModel is treated as transient regardless.  Maybe this situation warrants a github issue?

Comment: Correct - I just didn't clean up the transient decorator, but it doesn't really apply here.  In this situation, transient is the default behavior.  You can use `@singleton()` to instruct the router to reuse the instance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there's no way for a custom element to use a singleton view model.  So multiple elements would have each their own view model that gets constructed.  But this case is a little different - it seems that the templating engine is hanging onto the element reference and adding it back as opposed to creating it from scratch.  A github issue might spur some conversation about this behavior.

Comment: You're right.  Compose is basically the only way to accompish this right now. https://github.com/aurelia/framework/issues/602  Thanks for taking the time to look into it!